# Make a widget re-render everytime parent website URL changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a widget and adding it on a react website. Widget does specific tasks based on the URL.

Let's say, I want widget to appear exactly when URL is [www.company.com](http://www.company.com). But the widget appears on "www.company.com/welcome" as well if the user navigated through history.push/ or replace.

Only when a state Change happens inside widget on [www.company.com/welcome](http://www.company.com/welcome), it realizes, "oh I am not supposed to appear here".

I'm quite new to programming. I want the widget to re-render everytime the parent website URL changes(and not wait for any state change inside Widget). How to do this?

Currently, this is how finding current URL. I tried 2 approaches.

In the first approach here, on some state change, widget realises it shouldn't come here.....but it requires that state change.

```
const Main =() ={

let currentUrl = window.location.href;

}
```

In the 2nd approach, it doesn't work even after a state change.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let url = window.location.href;
    setCurrentURL(url)

},[currentUrl]);
```

3rd approach suggested by user, behaves exactly like the above issue.

```
const Main =() ={
const [url, setUrl] = useState(window.location.href);

}
```

Something interesting : The widget works properly when it is added on a html website when moved between pages or when navigation is through window.location ="/"

Only when Parent website is navigated through history.push or history.replace and widget doesn't seem to render.

If it's a stupid mistake, feel free to let me know. I have wasted too much time on this problem already and would appreciate any sort of help

Comment: You could use conditional rendering in your parent component, something like: `<Main>{ currentUrl === allowedUrl  ? <Widget/> : null }</Main>`

Comment: @tromgy currentUrl doesn't change unless there is a state change. That is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried looking at useEffect?

DOC: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
useEffect(() => {
 //****DO SOMETHING HERE WITH YOUR WIDGITS HERE****
}, []); //
```

you are currently storing the
`let currentUrl = window.location.href;`
in a variable are you sure you don't want to use useState() hook?

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Main =() ={
const [url, setUrl] = useState(window.location.href);

}
```

Comment: Yeah. I have added that in the question with the associated problem

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is when the page (Parent) URL change the widget doesn't re-render. So when users move from Page A to Page B, the widget is still under the impression I am still at Page A. How to re-render widget when parent URL changes - this issue needs fix.

Comment: please try the useEffect without the [currentUrl] dependency as useEffect works everytime the page is loaded so this should work. just remove the current url []

Comment: Nope still not working. Widget doesn't seem to understand the parent website URL has changed. Once it identifies it, then everything works well.